# How to add data to a Jtable in java upon user giving the data and then get the data at the end?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

what I want is, the user to enter in the textfields, once they press ok, I want that to be added onto the jtable, they add another option I want that to be added onto the jtable and so on. Once they have added it I want to get the values of the Jtable and execute it say print it out but the order they added it.

I have designed a combobox, 3 textfields, a label which when clicked adds the data to the JTable. below is my code so far.

```
JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
    comboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "NONE","A","B","C","D" }));
    comboBox1.setBounds(40, 20, 200, 40);
    contentPane.add(comboBox1);

JTextField time = new JTextField();
time.setBounds(216, 135, 45, 30);
contentPane.add(time);

JTextField speed1 = new JTextField();
speed1.setBounds(273, 135, 45, 30);
contentPane.add(speed1);

JTextField speed2 = new JTextField();
speed2.setBounds(328, 135, 45, 30);
contentPane.add(speed2);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Add this to table");
label1.setBounds(310, 200, 100, 20);
contentPane.add(label1);

JTable table_2 = new JTable();
table_2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
    new Object[][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
    },
    new String[] {
        "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
    }
));
table_2.setBounds(20, 200, 360, 100);
contentPane.add(table_2);
```

The user can add values to the Jtable in any order, say user chooses A from combobox, types 2 in field time, 10 in field speed 1 and 10 in field speed 2. and then they add say B and information for that, and C, D, and B again or in any other other, or they choose just 1 option and what to execute that.

So say, user chooses or types B,2,5,6 and then presses add this to table, I want that to be added, they can add more, lets say they add 2 more different variations. How can I store them in the JTable, and then if I want to print them out at the end in the order they came in How can I do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Every time someone uses null layout and `setBounds(...)` a kitten dies somewhere. Please save the kittens -- just don't do this.

Comment: Regarding your actual problem -- I don't see the code where you attempt to solve it. Where is your JButton and its ActionListener that tries to create a row of data from the text fields and combo boxes and tries to add that data to the table? Without your attempt how can we guess what you could be doing wrong? I'm sure that you've gone through the JTable tutorial, and the DefaultTableModel API, and so must have an idea of how to add a row to a DefaultTableModel, correct?

Comment: I am sorry, I think I did not explain my self very clearly, currently I do not have a button because firstly what I am trying to figure out is that how can I put the value given by the user in the table. All I need to know after that is how can I retrieve those values when I need them. printing them out was just an example, I have been working on this for several hours know hence I am loosing concentrate but without resolving it I cannot rest. Once again, I am sorry for not expressing my self cleary.

Answer (score 2):

- You don't need to specify a bunch of empty cells/rows initially. Just us this constructor for the model

  ```
  DefaultTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount)
  ```

  Constructs a `DefaultTableModel` with as many columns as there are elements in columnNames and rowCount of null object values.

  ```
  String[] colNames = {"New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"};
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);
  ...
  table.setModel(model);
  ```
- Then you can just use this method to add rows

  ```
  public void addRow(Object[] rowData)
  ```

  Adds a row to the end of the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.
   Something like

  ```
   String cBoxSelection = (String)comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
   String speed1String = speed1.getText();
   String speed2String = speed2.getText();
   String timeString = time.getText();

   String[] row = {cBoxSelection, speed1String, speed2String, timeString};
   model.addRow(row);
  ```
- If you want to traverse the model to print the items, just make use of these methods

  ```
   getColumnCount()
  ```

  Returns the number of columns in this data table.

  ```
   getRowCount()
  ```

  Returns the number of rows in this data table.

  ```
   getValueAt(int row, int column)
  ```

  Returns an attribute value for the cell at row and column.
  So you could do something like this

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++ ){
       for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
           System.out.printf("%10s", model.getValueAt(i, j));
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
  ```

---

**Side Note**

- As @HovercraftFullOfEels noted, don't use null layout. Have a look at [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Layout managers will make your layouts more flexible for different look and feels an machine
- You should wrap your `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`.

  ```
  JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
  contentPane.add(scroll);
  ```
- You should specify the size of your `JTextFields` using this constructor

  ```
  JTextField(int columns)
  ```

  Where `columns` is the character length of the field.

---

> "how can I retrieve those values when I need them"

You need to make them class member variables. Right now they look like they're localized n the constructor. Here's what I mean by class member

```
public class MyClass {
    private JTextField time;
    private JTextField speed1;

    public MyClass() {
        time = new JTextField(10);
        speed1 = new JtextField(10);
    }
}
```

No they can be accessed *outside* of the constructor as they now have a global scope. Currently they only have a *local* scope within the constructor.